# ORA-19914: unable to encrypt backup and ORA-28365: wallet is not open

Tags: oracle, backup, rman, oracle-19c

I have been taking backup of my database daily, and for some reason, I suddenly got this error

`ORA-19914: unable to encrypt backup ORA-28365: wallet is not open`

this is my databases's current encryption configuration:
SELECT STATUS FROM V$ENCRYPTION_WALLET;

```
STATUS
------------------------------
NOT_AVAILABLE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed.

```
rman target /
SHOW ALL
CONFIGURE ENCRYPTION FOR DATABASE OFF;
```

Once this config is changed, the backup started to work fine.